# VS Code no no-inline-styles

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj5XA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj5XA.png)

```
<header style="margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
```

`On header there has a yellow underline and button has a red underline but I can start I want to disable the no-inline-style`

I seacrhed on the internet

Comment: what's your question? you want to disable that warning? Because I don't know how to disable only that warning without disabling all other webhint warnings: `"vscode-edge-devtools.webhint": false` in settings.json.

Comment: It is just a warning. If you want to ignore it you can ignore it. Otherwise follow the suggestion from the image you shared.